# file_get_contents fails via php, works via browser

Tags: php, curl, timeout, file-get-contents, simplexml

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Get request to an API Endpoint, retrieving an XML and subsequently parse the results.
I am sending a `file_get_contents` request to achieve this.

**Issues:**

```
`file_get_Contents` fails, error:  

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json):
failed to open stream: 
        A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond.
```

**Update 17/08**

To consolidate my current understanding:
**1. PHP FAILS:**
1.a it fails via php (timeout)
1.b it fails via command line (curl -G http://api.eve-central.com/api/quicklook?typeid=34)
1.c file_get_contents
1.d file_get_contents w/ create_stream_context

**2. What WORKS:**
2.a Pasting the url in a chrome tab
2.b via postman

**What has been attempted:**
- Check Headers in Postman ,and try to replicate them via php

```
Postman Headers sent back by eve-central:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *  
Connection → Keep-Alive  
Content-Encoding → gzip  
Content-Type → text/xml; charset=UTF-8  
Date → Wed, 17 Aug 2016 10:40:24 GMT  
Proxy-Connection → Keep-Alive  
Server → nginx  
Transfer-Encoding → chunked  
Vary → Accept-Encoding  
Via → HTTP/1.1 proxy10014
```

Corresponding Code:

```
$headers = array(     
'method'  => 'GET',        
'header'  => 'Connection: Keep-Alive', 
'header'  => 'Content-Encoding: gzip', 
'header'  => 'Content-Type: text/xml',
'header'  => 'Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive', 
'header'  => 'Server: nginx', 
'header'  => 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked', 
'header'  => 'Vary: Accept-Encoding', 
'header'  => 'Via: HTTP/1.1 proxy10014');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT , 8080); // Attempt at changing port in the event it was blocked.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST,           false );            
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_error($curl))
{
echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl);
}
```

- Use Wireshark to capture the GET request to see if changing the port helped
- Run cUrl via command line
  I'm out of ideas and option.
  So the questions are:

  1. If it works in a browser, and in Postman, why does it not work via PHP ?
  2. How can I modify my code so that it mimics what Postman does? ?

Previous Attempts
**What I have tried:**
Various cURL options from other threads, such as

```
function curl_get_contents($url) { 
$ch = curl_init();
if (!$ch) 
{
die("Couldn't initialize a cURL handle");
} else
echo "Curl Handle initialized ";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
// Check if any error occurred
if (!curl_errno($ch)) 
{
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo 'Took ', $info['total_time'], ' seconds to send a request to ', $info['url'], "";
displayData($info);
} else
echo "Failed Curl, reason: ".curl_error($ch)." ";
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

**result:** nothing, no data returned.
- **Checked php.ini options:**
- allow_fopen is On
- allow_url_include = on
- relevant ssl extensions are enabled
- **Raised the timeout window**
- both via php.ini
- also via explicit declaration within the php file.
- **Tried with a different url**
- same error, so it doesn't really depends on my particular endpoint
- for example, both twitter/wikipedia/google return the specific error
- **tried with:**
- file_get_contents on a local xml file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx) --> **works**
- file_get_contents on a remote xml file     (http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/note.xml) --> **fails** same error
- **Overall, the following is true, so far:**
- Curl fails, timeout
- file_get_Contents fails, timeout
- Open XML file url in a browser works
- Make a GET request via Postman, works

Obviously, in all cases where the `file_get_contents` fails via php, I can easily access the file via any browser.

Tried to work around the issue.
Attempt 1:
Use nitrous.io, create a LAMP stack, perform the deed via the platform
results: file_get_contents works, however, due to the large number of xml files to be retrieved, the operation times-out.
Tentative solution:
- Download XML files from source
- Zip them
- Download xml_file
- Locally parse said xml files
Later on, write a small php scripts that, when invoked, performs the bits above, sends the data to the local directory, which then unpacks it and performs additional work on it.
Another attempt would be to use Google Sheets, with a user function that pulls the data into the sheet, and just dump the excel file / values into mysql.
For my purposes, while an awfully ignorant solution, it does the trick.

Code used for avoiding timeout issue on shared host:

```
function downloadUrlToFile2($url, $outFileName)
{
    //file_put_contents($xmlFileName, fopen($link, 'r'));
    //copy($link, $xmlFileName); // download xml file
    ;
    echo "Passing $url into $outFileName ";
    // $outFileName = touch();
    $fp = fopen($outFileName, "w");
    if(is_file($url)) 
    {
        copy($url, $outFileName); // download xml file
    } else 
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            $options = array(
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800, // set this to 8 hours so we dont timeout on big files
            CURLOPT_URL     => $url
        );

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
            $contents = curl_exec($ch);
            fwrite($fp, $contents);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
}
```

I have also added this on top of the ini script:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

Comment: You are trying to fetch data without doing any authentication mechanism. Why don't you try one of the PHP wrapper for Twitter? https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries

Comment: thank you for your reply.
Twitter url was just one of the random URLs used to try out different options.

The results doesn't change if you do a file_get_contents($url), with $url being: http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/note.xml. 

So, as you can see from that url, it's a plain xml, with no auth required of any kinds, still fails w/ the timeout error.

Comment: Where is the code running? Have you hecked that the machine you are running this on has a direct internet connection? (a server may be sitting behind a preverse proxy) That it can resolve names? That it doesn't have a firewall preventing this access? That it is not restricted by another security mechanism? Did you check the logs? Its common to configure webserver hosts to prevent them making outgoing connections across the internet for security reasons (and is the default with Redhat's SELinux policy).

Comment: I can access internet. I can access for example http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/note.xml via Chrome, but not via file_get_contents or curl. However, your point may be valid. I shall try to execute the same code from my home pc to ensure it's not a proxy/firewall rule.

Still, if I can make a get request via a browser, and get the xml displayed properly, I should be able to do so as well via php, no ? After all, they use the same http stack, including curl, to retrieve data

Answer (score 3):

I see some issue with HTTPS url request, for fix issue you have to add below lines in your CURL request

```
function curl_get_contents($url) { 
    $ch = curl_init();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: ";
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header ); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    // I have added below two lines
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
I incorporate your feedback and added some more error trapping:
Will add the code to the original block. What is interesting, is that the curl timeouts as well:

      Getting contents from http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/note.xml

    Curl Handle initialized 

    Failed Curl, reason: Connection timed out after 5008 milliseconds

Comment: @user3375601 I have the same issue for one URL which is working browser but it is not working in php through the file_get_content and curl request.